# TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'join_axes'

Tags: python, concatenation

Good morning,

I'm new to programming and using python.  I'm trying to use this

```
Genre = movie_ratings_selected_df['Genres']
Genre = Genre.str.get_dummies().add_prefix('Genres_')
movie_ratings_genres_df = pd.concat(
    [movie_ratings_selected_df.drop(
        ['Genres'],
        axis=1
    ),
>     Genre],
>    axis=1,
>    join_axes=[movie_ratings_selected_df.index]
>)
>movie_ratings_genres_df.head()
```

And I get this error, that's way above me right now...

```
TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'join_axes'
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Assuming you're using pandas (since you didn't specify) pandas concat _doesn't_ have an argument called `join_axes`. See [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for a list of the arguments it does take

Comment: Right. It has a `join` keyword and an `axis` keyword, but they do distinct things.

Answer (score 1):

Join_axes code is no longer supported in the new version of Pandas. You need to use reindex() instead.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that join axes is not a valid argument for the function pd.concat(),
try reviewing the documentation for this function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html